# Error Like Receiver not register while using Camera activity in api level 8

Tags: android

In my one of application i got an error like reciever not register
       android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@4832dd18  while using camera even i dont use any view 
       flipper in my xml.

**the error Log is like that :**

```
     09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@4832dd18
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:793)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:900)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.widget.ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow(ViewFlipper.java:104)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6033)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1158)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1655)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2698)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2668)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:251)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3684)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3789)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-17 12:21:36.773: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11744): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

in my another application camera activity works good without giving such an error..
   code for camera activity is same for both application..
   so what do u mean by this error.

please help me as early as possible..

Thanking you....

Answer (score 0):

You have to register receiver in manifest file